# saving photos with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have installed paperclip on my rails app (deployed on heroku).
On my localhost it worked fine, but on heroku it didnt work.

I looked at the log and found that this is the problem:

```
Errno::EACCES(Permission denied - /app/723a45cd/home/public/system):
```

It looks like it dont have permissions for "system" folder (its the pictures folder).

How I solve this?
Should I give the app permissions? If yes, how?

Thanks,

Oded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can store uploaded files on Heroku, you'll have to use S3 as [described in their documentation](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).

Answer (score 1):

Heroku has a [read-only file system](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem) (except the /tmp directory) which means you'll need to save your images elsewhere. Probably the best place is Amazon S3, which Paperclip happens to [support natively](http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/master/Paperclip/Storage/S3).